# Simple code that reads CSV values causes an error in System.IO.Directory

Tags: vb.net, csv, directoryinfo

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a compilation error with this code that tries to find the most recently updated file (all CSV files) in a directory, to then pull the last line of the CSV and update a device.

The exception I get is:

> Line 3 Character 10 expected end of statement.

Don't worry about the `hs.SetDevice`, I know that part is correct.

```
Imports System.IO

Sub Main()
    Dim path = System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("C:\Users\Ian\Documents\Wifi Sensor Software").OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First()
    Dim line = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path).Last()
    Dim fields() = line.Split(",".ToCharArray())
    Dim fileTemp = fields(2)
    hs.SetDeviceValueByRef(124, fileTemp, True)
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Changed Directory to `DirectoryInfo`

Comment: Be careful about splitting based on `,` if one cel includes this character everything is done in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The original problem was that [Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) returns an array of strings, a string doesn't have a `LastWriteTime` Property.
  This property belongs to the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) base class, [FileSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo), the object type returned by [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles).
  Then, a `FileInfo` object cannot be passed to `File.ReadLines()`, this method expects a string, so you need to pass `[FileInfo].FullName`.
- Hard-coding a Path in that manner is not a good thing. Use [Environment.GetFolderPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) to get the Path of special folders, as the MyDocuments folder, and [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to build a valid path.
- Better use the [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) class to parse a CSV file. It's very simple to use and safe enough.

The worst problem is [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) set to `Off`.
Turn it `On` in the Project's Properties (`Project->Properties->Compile`), or in the general options of Visual Studio (`Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VB Defaults`), so it's already set for new Projects.
You can also add it on top of a file, as shown here.

With `Option Strict On`, you are immediately informed when a mishap of this kind is found in your code, so you can fix it immediately.
With `Option Strict Off`, some issues that come up at run-time can be very hard to identify and fix. Setting it `On` to try and fix the problem later is almost useless, since all the mishaps will come up all at once and you'll have a gazillion of error notifications that will hide the issue at hand.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Dim filesPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Wifi Sensor Software")
Dim mostRecentFile = New DirectoryInfo(filesPath).
    GetFiles("*.csv").OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First()

Using tfp As New TextFieldParser(mostRecentFile.FullName)
    tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
    tfp.SetDelimiters({","})

    Dim fileTemp As String = String.Empty
    Try
        While Not tfp.EndOfData
            fileTemp = tfp.ReadFields()(2)
        End While
    Catch fnfEx As FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show($"File not found: {fnfEx.Message}")
    Catch exIDX As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show($"Invalid Data format: {exIDX.Message}")
    Catch exIO As MalformedLineException
        MessageBox.Show($"Invalid Data format at line {exIO.Message}")
    End Try
  
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileTemp) Then
        hs.SetDeviceValueByRef(124, fileTemp, True)
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working. It was my fault. My environment wasn't set up correctly and I was making beginner .net mistakes. Thank you for giving me something to analyze and work on to beef up my .net skills.